# Karma test paste event

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a simple component that handle paste event into a form input.

The form:

```
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  query: [ null, [Validators.required] ]
});

onPaste(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formattedQuery = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
      .split(/,?[\r\n\t]+\s?/)
      .join(', ')
      .replace(/,\s?$/g, '');

    this.searchForm.get('query').setValue(formattedQuery);
  }
```

Now I am trying to test that and it looks like this:

```
it('should reformat pasted data', () => {
    const queryField = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type="search"]'));
    queryField.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
      dataType: 'text/plain', 
      data: '123\r123'
    }));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(queryField.nativeElement.value).toBe('123, 123');
    // also tried expect(component.searchForm.get('query').value).toBe('123, 123');
  });
```

But as a result i've got

```
Expected '' to be '123, 123'
```

If i do `console.log(queryField.nativeElement)` it shows the input, but why it doesn't handle `new ClipboardEvent('paste')` event?

```
<input class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="query" type="search" ng-reflect-name="query">
```

Full component you can find here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cp9yhx?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

What's wrong with my unit test?

Comment: Did you try it without `fixture.detectChanges()` ?

Comment: i did. same result (

Comment: Where does value `325435956, 325435956` come from? Did you set it somewhere before the test? Like, in beforeEach?

Comment: oops, i am sorry, i tried different numbers. let's assume it's '123, 123'

Comment: try calling onPaste directly. So instead of dispatching the event on the element `queryField.nativeElement.dispatchEvent....` try calling `onPaste( new ClipboardEvent(....` and see if it helps.

Comment: `TypeError: queryField.nativeElement.onPaste is not a function` and `TypeError: queryField.onPaste is not a function`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
it('should reformat pasted data', () => {
  component.onPaste(new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
    dataType: 'text/plain', 
    data: '123\r123'
  }));
  expect(queryField.nativeElement.value).toBe('123, 123');
});
```

Or even

```
it('should reformat pasted data', () => {
  component.onPaste(new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
    dataType: 'text/plain', 
    data: '123\r123'
  }));
  expect(component.searchForm.get('query').value).toBe('123, 123');
});
```

Comment: i am sorry, but i've got the same result `Expected '' to be '123, 123'.` i've copy pasted your both examples without any changes

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
it('should trim pasted data', () => {
  const initialValue = 'test ';
  fixture.detectChanges();

  // Setting initial value
  const el = inputElement.nativeElement;
  el.value = initialValue;

  // Setting up event data
  const pasteData = new DataTransfer();
  pasteData.setData('text', initialValue);

  // Creating event
  const pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
    clipboardData: 'new value'  <- CHANGED
  } as any);


  // Dispatching event    
  el.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent);

  expect(el.value).toEqual('new value'); <- CHANGED
});
```

Comment: no, it just looks like it works because of   el.value = initialValue;

Comment: Thank you @ed4becky. How stupid of me. I updated the answer.

Comment: what's the use of pasteData?